# Debugging C# Bot in VS 2019 issue - no response in Bot after sending Bot a message through MS Teams

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, ngrok

I have a Bot that has been programmed in C# using the Bot Framework in .NET 4.8. This Bot has a Bots Channels Registration in Azure, which hooks into an existing app registration in Azure Active Directory, which is where my App ID originates from along with the App Secret. Now to debug my Bot I run Ngrok to tunnel the URL to my localhost at port 3980, which is what the Bot runs in when I debug it. As you can see below the messaging endpoint is the ngrok URL with the "api/messages" part maintained, which is the API endpoint that all messages from MS Teams will go to in my Bot.

[image]

The App ID here matches the one of the app registration and the one in my web.config file. I have checked the "app settings" in my web.config file along with the connection string and they are correct.

[image]

[image]

When I send a message to my Bot in MS Teams nothing comes through and nothing is picked up in the ngrok inspector (http://127.0.0.1:4040/inspect/http).

[image]

I would expect this breakpoint to be hit once a message from MS Teams is sent to the Bot.

[image]

However, it doesn't get hit and no error or exception is thrown. Nothing is either picked up in the ngrok terminal. I've tried switching my firewall off thinking it may have been security related but this didn't change the outcome. When I change the messaging endpoint to be that of the actual hosted Bot app url, the Bot responds as expected when a message is sent to it in MS Teams. This used to work before when trying to debug using ngrok but now it has suddenly stopped working. Any ideas on what the problem might be? Has anything changed at the ngrok or azure end possibly that I've missed? Any help would be much appreciated on this, thanks!

Comment: I was able to debug sample [54.teams-task-module](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module) with ngroks url `https://myngrok.io/api/messages`set in azure bot service. Are you able to reproduce this behavior using emulator alone?

Answer (score 0):

To check the functionality of bot, the first steps is to test it in **WEB CHAT**. When the bot was created using any programming language (**language is not a major criterion for error**), the following will be the possible errors:

- Not being able to respond (the current issue)
- Throwing errors (As there are no errors in your case)
- Working in one channel and error in remaining channels.

When we test the bot using **WEB CHAT** we can determine the reason for the error, whether it is with bot side or from particular channel (**MS Teams in this case**).

**Test in Web Chat:**
There must be a fully functional and ready to use bot must be available to test.

- Goto Azure portal (portal.azure.com)
- Open the "**Test in Web Chat**" option
- Try to send message to your bot.

[image]

If the bot is not responding to the message, refer "**[bot is not working in web chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-does-not-work-in-web-chat)**" and if the case is like "**[bot working in one platform and not working in other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-works-in-web-chat-but-not-in-other-channels)**"

Check the channel configuration issues **[from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots)**.

Document Credit [@JonathanFingold](https://github.com/JonathanFingold) and team